# Should I write jupyter_server or jupyter-server when using pip install?

Tags: python, pip, jupyter

When pip installing the jupyter server package, it seems that

```
pip install jupyter_server
```

and

```
pip install jupyter-server
```

do the same thing.

Is that right? Why are the package names with underscore and hyphen both OK?

The same goes to jupyter_client and jupyter-client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pip replaces underscore with dash by default, so you always install the same package (jupyter-server).